# Materialize css initializing tabs for each result

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I am doing a school project that is a Movie lookup app connected to guidebox API. I am using Materialize CSS and trying to organize the information into their tabs system. They are added dynamically so the documentation says to initialize in javascript. It says to use:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('ul.tabs').tabs();
      });
```

However that doesn't work for me I guess since the tabs are not present at Doc Ready thaey are not pushed into the DOM until a submit request. I put just the

```
      $('ul.tabs').tabs();
```

into a few places in my code and the best result was it working on the first movie returned on each search but for each subsequent return item the tabs break.

I could use some guidance on whether I can plug that in somewhere to make my existing code work.

https://github.com/jasonboru/group_project1_guidebox.git

Comment: Call $('ul.tabs').tabs();   in your foreach loop, immediately after adding the new element to the dom

Comment: I'm obviously mistaken but, that I thought that is where I had it currently. However the tabs only work on the first element returned. I have it immediatly after
        $('.guidebox-search-results').append(movieResult);

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing ending tags in your dynamically created dom elements.

Apart this, in this file  ***assets/js/logic.js*** the following there are the following two lines:

```
$('.guidebox-search-results').append(movieResult);
$('ul.tabs').tabs();
```

That menas, whenever you add new tabs element you initialize them.
The mistake I see is: in this way you initialize every tabs not only the new one. And, because you have already initilized the old one I can suggest you to rewrite the previous two lines in this format:

```
$('.guidebox-search-results').append(movieResult);
$('.guidebox-search-results').find('ul.tabs').tabs();
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of since, but I am still getting the same results. You mentioned to rewrite both lines but the top line looks identical, Was there supposed to be some change there?
I did find a missing closing anchor tag on one line but fixing it did not help. I'll keep combing over it for other errors.
Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: The problem turned out to be silly on my end. When writing out the tabs I gave each div an ID that each tab would link to like the Materialize documentation said. I didn't think it through though because each result would populate with the same set of IDs. Since IDs are unique it was only working with the first result. I changed the id for each to add in a unique number from the JSON of that result and that gave me unique id's for each movie and solved the issue.

Comment: @Jason I'm glad for you. Never forget IDs must be unique.  Thanks so much for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind on every event, when node inserted in dom and after that, do with it what you want.

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
});
```

Comment: Sorry Im new to this and not sure how to apply it. i tried by itself before the function that adds the element and it did not work. Then I tried adding the initialize into your suggested function and I got the error. Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: [DOMNodeInserted: is Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and this is not the issue the op is experiencing.